# Set Button width to "fullwidth" of parent

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to set the width of a button (Material-UI) to fit the width of the parent, a drawer.

According to the doc, I used style injection and "fullwidth" property but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Thank's

Answer (score 1):

I should learn to read ..... :) It's simply "fullWidth" .... not inject in style.

```
<Button variant="extendedFab" color="primary" fullWidth>Folder</Button>
```